# Firebase warning: consent indicators not collected for ad personalization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, ump

Premise I have already Google UMP configured for Admob and I have already added the manifest values reported [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?consentmode=advanced&platform=android) for Firebase Analytics

In the past week now I have seen this warning in the Firebase profile of my Android App

> End users in the European Economic Area (EEA) must provide consent to
> have their personal data shared with Google for advertising purposes.
> If data is marked as non-consent, ad personalization and measurement
> may be affected. Check your Firebase consent settings.

If I check Google Analytics in stream details I have:

> **ACTION REQUIRED**
> Consent indicators not collected for ad personalization Action
> required To verify that your business is collecting consent from the end
> Users in the EEA before submitting personal data to Google for use in
> ad personalization, implement consent indicators for ad
> personalization. If personal data is not marked with end-user consent,
> EEA-based visitors will not be included in audience lists exported to
> Google Ads and will impact ad personalization. To set up consent
> indicators, use a consent management platform or the Consensus Mode
> API. Learn more about consensus indicators You may need to update the
> Google Analytics for Firebase SDKs for Android and iOS to a version
> that supports the consent indicators required for EEA-based visitors
> (Android: 21.5.0, iOS: 10.17.0).

The `google-services.json` is updated and I have the latest `firebase-analytics:21.5.1` and `ump:user-messaging-platform:2.2.0` and `com.google.gms:google-services` is also updated to the latest version.

How should I fix this error?

Comment: Have same problem. I cannot find a solution anywhere, no one describes a similar problem. My implementation is same as google documentation.

Comment: check this firebase documentation https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?platform=android&consentmode=advanced

Comment: @ashakirov the link you have posted is the one that I have already mentioned in the question

Comment: @Kenumir same here, I have followed all the instructions there but I continue to have this persistent error as if the stream receives traffic from European countries but not the required consent indicators.

Comment: On Firebase github has issue reported - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5731 - No major interest

Comment: @Kenumir bug is reported recently, I don't know how many accounts could have been affected probably the bug appears only under specific circumstances for specific accounts. Remains the fact that my configuration follow the guidelines reported as explained but Firebase seems is not detecting any consent indicator.

Comment: Problem probably solved https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5738